# Not able to add web project to tomcat server "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server" - Java 17

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server, facet

After migrating the Eclipse (2021-9) workspace to Java 17, it is not possible any longer to add the Web project to the tomcat server.
Tomcat version is 9.0.54. All projects have Project Facet 17 and the related java 17 JRE.
Also the plugin 'Java 17 Support for Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21)' has been installed.
But adding the web project to the tomcat server is not working any longer. I get the message "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server".

It only works when I set the project facet of this Web project back to Java 11 again. But that is not what we want.
So far I didn't find a solution for this problem. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It's a reported [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/576466).

Answer (score 1):

## Bug

This appears to be a known bug in Eclipse:

[*Bug 576466 - Can't add Java 17 WebApplication to Tomcat9*](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576466)

## Workaround

As for a workaround, the author of the bug report mentions Eclipse does work properly if you switch to using Tomcat version 10.

FYI, versions of 9.x and 10.0 of Tomcat are special in that they are virtually identical, developed in parallel, the main difference being the switch in package names from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` as part of compliance with Jakarta 9.0.  See [*Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE*](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) by Arjan Tijms.

Furthermore, Tomcat 10.1 is built to support Java 11, as part of compliance with [Jakarta 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/release/9.1/). Since you are using Java 17, I would suggest using Tomcat 10.1.x in your situation.